# Ideas with REGEX Formatting

Tags: java, android

Can anyone help please.
I am trying to figure out a Regex format for some data, but am struggling with its complexities.

I want to format some Latitude EditText in the format

"N5123.5"

The first digit must be either N or S (or n or s)
There must be then exactly 4 numerics, exactly 1 full stop
and then exactly 1 digit. Therefore the length must be exactly 7 characters long.
I have tried various although the one I believed it to be was

```
static final Pattern LAT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^[NSns]{1}[0-9]{4}[.]{1}[0-9]{1}");
```

However this doesn't work.
Any experts out there could help please.

Comment: Usually, it's a good idea to write exactly what you mean by "doesn't work". Also, I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to do with the regex. Format some text? Regexes are for matching, not formatting...

Answer (score 2):

Those `{1}`s can be dropped (although they don't affect the match). But you need to anchor the regex at the end of the string, too, or longer strings than 7 characters could also (partially) match:

```
Pattern.compile("^[NSns][0-9]{4}[.][0-9]$");
```

Usually, the dot is written as `\.`, not `[.]`, but both are OK, especially in Java with its double-backslash needs:

```
Pattern.compile("^[NSns][0-9]{4}\\.[0-9]$");
```

Comment: _"although they don't hurt"_, they hurt my eyes! :)

Comment: @BartKiers: Right you are. I've reworded it slightly.

Answer (score 0):

the regex you have looks right to me but anchor the regex to beginning and end only work if there is nothing in front of or behind so if that is in the middle of the string then remove ^ at the front and the dot operator in the class i would think would work [.] as it loses special meaning there

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the replies. I have spent some time and got to grips a little with this.
The result I have used is:

```
static final Pattern LAT_PATTERN_WRK = Pattern.compile("^([NSns]{0,1}$)|" +
                                "^([NnSs]([0-9])$)|" +
                                "^([NnSs]([0-9]{2})$)|" +
                                "^([NnSs]([0-9]{3})$)|" +
                                "^([NnSs]([0-9]{4})$)|" +
                                "^([NnSs]([0-9]{4})\\.$)|" +
                                "^([NnSs]([0-9]{4})\\.[0-9]$)");
                             "^([NnSs]([0-9]{1,4})\\.[0-9]$)");
```

The reason for this being so complicated is that I wanted to put real time validation onto an EditText box. That way only valid values could be keyed in. It will now only accept

```
adEtLat.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() > 0 && !LAT_PATTERN_WRK.matcher(s).matches()) {
                String input = s.toString();
                adEtLat.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                adEtLat.setText(input.substring(0, input.length()-1));
                adEtLat.setSelection(input.length()-1);
                adEtLat.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
            @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
            @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });
```

Beginning with N,S,n,s or
Beginning with N,S,n,s and up to 4 numbers or
Beginning with N,S,n,s and up to 4 numbers and "." or
Beginning with N,S,n,s and up to 4 numbers and "." and 1 number.

When I do the form validation I will only validate against

```
static final Pattern CODE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^([NnSs]([0-9]{4})\\.[0-9]$)");
```

Thanks for all the help, it was really useful.

Answer (score -1):

I believe, you have problem in `[.]` - this means any character, `.` is `\.` (escaped) in regex.

So try:

- If you need validate single string: `^([NSns]{1}){1}\d{4}\.{1}\d{1}$`
- If you need find all references of your patter in string: `([NSns]{1}){1}\d{4}\.{1}\d{1}`
- If you ment that quotes to include too: `\"([NSns]{1}){1}\d{4}\.{1}\d{1}\"`

Let me know if it doesn't work ;-)

Comment: Nope, inside a character class, the `.` is no meta char, and matches a literal `'.'`, so `[.]` is fine.

Comment: `([NSns]{1}){1}` is like saying: _"I give you one apple, and multiply it by 1, and that amount I'll also multiply by 1. Here's your (single!) apple."_ :)